# How to use PATCH request in Azure Data Factory - Web Activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a file in my blob storage which has a set of unique numbers (identifiers). I need to pass this file content through Web Activity - PATCH request. Can someone please tell me how to pass the content of a file using PATCH activity?

I have tried to use 1st Web activity to access the entire storage url of the file and in the 2nd web activity , pass the content of the file via PATCH. Please guide me how to set up the 2nd activity. Or if there is any other process to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use a Lookup Activity in ADF which will output the contents of your Blob file, then pass the output of the Lookup to the Web Activity.

It is very similar to this:

[image: Example Pipeline]

Here are the details in the Set Variable activity and Web Activity (this is mockup):

[image: Set Variable Activity]

[image: Web Activity Details]

You can skip the set variable step and directly call the value of the Lookup Activity in the web call using the code from the set variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time. I regret to say that I tried to implement the above steps multiple times. Also , i used the storage URL of the file to pass to an WebActivity. None of the ways worked out.  Is there any other way we can do this?

Comment: Did the lookup work at all to get the contents within the Blob? That's the first part.

Comment: Hello... yes lookup was working fine to fetch details of the blob. Set variable activity also worked as expected. But somehow the body of the web activity is not able to read output of lookup / variable. Debugging the pipeline shows the input to web activity as expected. But it's failing.

Comment: Is the body supposed to be json? Like do you have a Content-Type: application/json? If it needs to be a different format, then you will have to convert to XML or text or some other format. You could also explicitly get the Output Values for each Body input. So rather than just taking the whole Output and using that as body, actually specify the body like {"param1": "@{outputValue1}", "param2": "@outputValue2", etc